How to define roles for users with ldap login module in Confluent Schema Registry?
I'm working on integrating the LdapLoginModule with Schema Registry service. I have successfully added this module to the service and can authenticate to Schema Registry APIs using LDAP authentication. However, I'm receiving 403 Forbidden responses from the service, because the user does not have any role. Confluent recommended using Basic HTTP Authentication with PropertyFileLoginModule, where roles are defined in a password file but ı dont want use this module. Is there a way to define LDAP users' roles when using LdapLoginModule?. Below is sample my jaas.conf and auth section configuration's ;
SchemaRegistryServer { com.sun.security.auth.module.LdapLoginModule required userProvider="ldap://ldapserver.com:389/CN=Users,DC=net,DC=net" };
authentication.method=BASIC authentication.realm=SchemaRegistryServer authentication.roles=admin,user
I tried to use two login module(LdapLoginModule-PropertyFileLoginModule) in order to define role in password-file. I wasn't very hopeful and it didn't work.
